# Submitting an abstract to many conferences

Tags: conference, abstract

I know that it is unethical to submit an article to many journals as reviewers spend time to read it. How about one abstract to many conferences? If you have specific time period to present your abstract and uncompleted work, do you think it is unethical to submit it to many conferences and choosing one of them to attend?

Comment: Why do you think it is any different?

Comment: Abstracts are generally one paragraph and no adjustment for abstracts in conferences. Moreover, conference deadlines and review phases are generally in the same time period for conferences in August for example. If you want to attend a conference in August and apply to one conference, you could lose other options after getting a rejection.

Comment: Is it common to be rejected from a conference in your field? I've literally never heard of someone being rejected from a conference in mine if you have a modicum of an idea where to submit.

Comment: You need to clarify what field this is about.  Conferences are very different between, for example, physics and computer science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unethical. You are still wasting people's time. Someone needs to read them and make decisions. Their time is valuable to them and to the community.  If everybody did such things then conferences would become untenable.

> "Hmmm, we had 30 accepted abstracts, but only 3 people showed up."

If you submit to a conference, expect to attend if accepted.

Workshops would be a different matter, assuming that you are able to attend them all.

Comment: This makes sense for computer science, but for large physics conferences, very little time is spent examining abstracts.